# Searchable in Datatables in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I need to disable searching option in certain column in datatable in runtime. There is an option to disable search on certain during [initialisation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.searchable) of Datatable but unfortunately it is not possible at runtime. Take for instance, we can control the visibility of a column even after the datatable is drawn , is there any option like this for Searching.

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: As a workaround, have you tried destroying the table and then recreating it with the searching option disabled for that column?

Comment: No, the table is huge and having a lot of configurations(which I dont store globally) . Trying to find a solution without recreating the table.

Comment: You could simply hide the search / filter box : `$('.dataTables_filter').hide();` when it is needed ...

Comment: Yes, but even if I make the visibility false of the column it's search results are still included in the search result.

Comment: Then override with default search with a custom search.

Comment: Can you elaborate how to do custom search ?